# Alternatives to client db storage in private browsing mode

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb, web-storage

I made a web service. When user logs in, the service creates the indexddb (idb) in openRequest.onupgradeneeded and writes data into the db in openRequest.onsuccess. Codes look like this,

```
export async function getCurrUser(window) {
    window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
    let  openRequest = indexedDB.open('userData',2);
    openRequest.onsuccess =  e =>{/*write data to db*/}
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded =  e => {/*build db*/}
    openRequest.onerror=e=> {//case private browsing}
}
```

in the private browsing mode, only openRequest.onerror is called; in my case, the user can never successfully log in. Since it's impossible to write all data into localstorage, I look for suitable alternatives for storage in private browsing mode. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The whole point of private browsing is to not have any visible effects once the private window is closed, right? Any potential persistent storage could be considered to be an undesirable data leak, I would think

Comment: no history saving, no cookie saving. like the firefox's new private window. So is it reasonable to limit the users to not use private browsing when they login my service? :p